# Is it possible to uses guards within guards?

Tags: haskell

I wonder if it is possible to use guards inside guards in haskell.
like this :

```
analyser modele instr
  |  instr == NoCom  = (modele, "No command" ,[])
  |  instr == ComK   | (read comargstr1) == 0 = function1 modele Nothing
                     | (read comargstr1) == 1 = function1 modele (Just (read comargstr1))
                     | (read comargstr1) <  0 = function1 modele (Just (read comargstr2))
                     | otherwise              = function2 modele
  | othercases...
  | othercases...
```

In my example, i can't evaluate (read comargstr1) in the first column of guards at all because comargstr1 doesn't always return a compatible string readable with read (fatal error)

I didn't managed to use guards within guards!

Is it possible to do it (Is there a trick, an option, something special, ...) or is it purely impossible?

Thank you in advance for your Help!

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not using pattern matching? I would have written `analyzer modele NoCom = ... ; analyzer modele ComK = case (read comargstr1) of { 0 -> f1 modele Nothing ; 1 -> f1 modele (Just 1) ; a1 | a1 < 0 -> f1 modele (Just (read comargstr2)) ; | otherwise -> f2 modele`   (Well actually I would have parsed the arguments first into a custom datatype and then dispatched based on the datatype, but at least the parsing part would start similarly...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layout doesn't apply to guards, so it doesn't matter how you align them.

The closest you can do is to use [MultiWayIf](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if) for the second-level guards.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something vaguely similar as follows:

```
analyser modele instr
  |  instr == NoCom = (modele, "No command" ,[])
  |  instr == ComK  = foo
  | othercases...
  | othercases...
  where foo | (read comargstr1) == 0 = function1 modele Nothing
            | (read comargstr1) == 1 = function1 modele (Just (read comargstr1))
            | (read comargstr1) <  0 = function1 modele (Just (read comargstr2))
            | otherwise              = function2 modele
```

Note that you will need a distinct name `foo` for every branch. Also, if a nested guard list does not end with `otherwise` (or equivalent) then control will *not* be transfered to the next guard in the topmost level.

Answer (score 0):

Just either repeat both conditions, or use an `if` after a single guard. Two/nested guards aren't supported as far as I'm aware.